# video with moving image as overlay

Tags: ruby, image, video, overlay

Ever heard of elfyourself? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gerWP7imzg8

I dont want to make a clone of elfyourself, but want to find a method to do the same combination of a video combined with moving images.

It would be perfect, if the resulting video can be embedded with HTML5 and work on popular browsers and smartphones (ios and android).

Requirements:

- Ruby as language.
- Place moving object on an existing video (its okay to do this with any tool what so ever).
- Let an user select an image.
- Serverside software should insert the user-selected image as the moving object.

The closest (not working) solution I can think of:

- Embed the video in Flash and create the moving object as overlay.
- Somehow let the Flash take the user-selected image as a parameter, so the image can be inserted as the moving object.
- Use FFMPEG to convert the SWF file to mp4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would do this is to use a simple gstreamer application. It will take care of the overlay and the transcoding in a single pipeline. In the future you could also have a "live" streaming solution from the same if you wanted. That ofcourse is dependent on your application.

Gstreamer has an element coglogoinsert which can overlay a png file. Advantage you can also allow transparency. With a simple application you can use the logo-x and logo-y parameters to change the location of the image at the interval you desire.

Gstreamer also has ruby bindings that are good enough to do this.

Comment: Is it also possible to rotate the image together with the logo-x and logo-y parameters?

Comment: Are you thinking of Ruby-GNOME2 (google suggested it) as the "good  enough" ruby binding?

Comment: Yes, Ruby Gnmoe2 is the ruby binding. I have used it to write very complex applications.  To do rotation you can use the videoflip element. There are couple of hundred plugins available in gstreamer to do most imaginable tasks that you wish to do with video. Take a look at it once. You can create quick prototypes on the command line using gst-launch and once you are satisfied you can write interactive applications as well (to change parameters on the fly).